# Will Excel run next line of VBA macro even if previous line is still calculating?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code the adds a vlookup formula to all rows with data, then copy/pastes the results as values. I've noticed with larger files, some cells result in "N/A" even though when I manually add the vlookup there is a valid result.

Is the code copy/pasting the values before the formula finishes calculating? Can a "wait" step be added to prevent this?

Edit: Here's the relevant lines of code. Line 1 inserts the vlookup, line 2 overwrites the formulas with the values:

```
awb.Worksheets("sheetABC").Range("J" & firstEmptyMeanRow & ":J" & loadMeanRow).Value = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],'All Questions_All Surveys'!C7:C9,3,FALSE)"
awb.Worksheets("sheetABC").Range("J" & firstEmptyMeanRow & ":J" & loadMeanRow).Value = awb.Worksheets("sheetABC").Range("J" & firstEmptyMeanRow & ":J" & loadMeanRow).Value2
```

Comment: Always helps to include your actual code

Comment: If all you need is the result of the lookup, try `Application.WorksheetFunction`

Comment: Added code, sorry! Is there a way to get it taken off hold now?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you recalculate before copying and pasting. Immediately after the line that adds the vlookup formula, add the following:

```
Application.Calculate
```